# ! File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg. error

Tags: errors, compiling

I wanted to compile my latex file and got an `! File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg` error without changing anything obviously in the code. I tried to look for missing brackets but couldn't find any mistake... I would be glad for help because the document is my masters thesis :( this is the minimal version of my code so far:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,bibliography=totoc,twoside=semi,numbers=noenddot,captions=tableheading,headsepline,BCOR=4mm,DIV=11]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}   % Deaktiviert Protrusion
\tableofcontents
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}    % Aktiviert Protrusion
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

    \include{00-Abstract}
    \include{01-Introduction}
    \include{02-Objectives}
    \include{03-Results}
    \include{04-Outlook}
    \include{05-Experimental}

    \printbibliography
    %\bibliography{bib}
    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code you showed seems fine. The problem probably is in one of the sub files you are including. Could you please make a small compilable code that reproduces the error (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))?

Comment: As Phelype says, please post a self contained minimal example that shows the problem, an exawe can copy and test as is

Comment: Thanks for your answer @daleif and @phelype! I didn't think of a problem in the subfiles and checked them and found a missing bracket in a caption... dump  I thought of a problem in the code but a s pheype already mentioned the error occured because of a sub file - thx